html file not displaying in chrome
html file not showing up when paste it into chrome url box
I am new. Building a super simple site. Just testing one line. When I click on "Open in" on my MacBook and I select "Chrome" the page opens just blankly.
Below is my text:
<header>
<title>
<h1>The Best Movies</h1>
</title>
</header>

Please help?

title represents the page title in the title bar or tab.

You need to research the basics: "Anatomy of an HTML document"
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>The Best Movies</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <header>
     <h1>The Best Movies</h1>
   </header>
  </body>
</html>

What you posted in your question appears you're trying to utilize the header element:
<header>
  <h1>The Best Movies</h1>
</header>

and you might be confusing this with the head:
<head>
  <title>The Best Movies</title>
</head>

because the document's title element is what defines:
<title>The Best Movies</title>

and is what you'd see in the browser tab.
Couple of other items:

With Chrome for Mac you can simply drag and drop an .html onto the opened browser and it should render
You just provided a block of code and it wasn't mentioned if you're bringing in the html doctype or head and body so if you take the above snippet and save it out as index.html in the editor of your choice you'll be able to drag and drop the file into Chrome and it will render.


I beg to differ. Given the context of the question, and providing research with a link for the questioner to better find info is provided along with the solution to his problem.

@DanielA.White Always welcome to provide an answer though

thank you for expanding your answer.

no worries. All of this is speculation given the context of the question.
